# Emotion as a conscious prediction error signal?

Tags: neuroscience

At first glance it seems many if not all emotions can be explained as prediction errors: hunger the observed level of energy stores is below expectation, anger the observed level of “respect” was below expectation, fear the observed level of personal safety was below expectation, disdain the observed level of respect afforded another person was above expectation, and so on. In addition, this explains the “motivational” component of emotion, namely to alter beliefs or execute actions to eliminate the prediction error in line with Friston’s free energy principle. Eg in the case of hunger, to eat, in the case of fear fight or flight, in the case of anger either dispute the offense to obtain a retraction or punish the offender, and so on. So I’ve found it surprising that it appears difficult to find research related to explaining emotions as “[active inference](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/active-inference)”. The closest I’ve found are [Emotions as computational signals of goal error](https://eshinjolly.com/assets/pdfs/Jolly_Emotions_Chapter.pdf)  and [Emotion and the predictive mind: Emotions as (almost) drives](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4983/6c1a2fd788c1e6b2c00923505f46bbfdb941.pdf?_ga=2.117490702.628428428.1625884282-1271957174.1625418017).
Is this an active area of research? Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Definition of emotion used is somewhat vague: is *hunger* an emotion? It has to do with real physical needs, like physical pain, whereas the other examples have to do with mental activity/relationships. Also, what about love, hate, curiosity, satisfaction, and many other emotions?

Comment: Well that’s the essence of the question.  Can some (or all) emotions be defined as conscious prediction error signals, where the predictions are the brain’s expectations about what it will observe. The expectations include priors like physical needs (which yield feelings such as hunger, thirst, oxygen hunger, salt hunger, pain, etc when they are violated) as well as learned beliefs about the causes of what it observes, which can be very high level explanations. The list is too long for this comment, but for example, embarrassment, my observed level of “competence” is below expectation.

Comment: It seems someone could define things this way for at least some emotions, but then....what's next? Why is that useful from a biology standpoint? There are predictive coding models for the brain but these are specified in terms of how the prediction errors propagate information within the brain.

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is that it could lead to a principled explanation of emotions in terms of free energy minimization, and if correct eventually to identification of the prediction error units and neuromodulators responsible.

Comment: @ChristopherOliver That doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, but seems to be stretching Friston's ideas further than even Friston would.